# Consume rest service in android which takes complex data type as parameter

Tags: android, jsonschema2pojo

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/CreatePerson", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
    EMPDetails CreatePerson(EMPDetails createPerson);

// Implementation
 public EMPDetails CreatePerson(EMPDetails createPerson)
    {
        EMPDetails detail = new EMPDetails();
        detail.Eid = 111;
        detail.Name = "Gopi";
        return detail;
    }

///data contract
 [DataContract]
  public class EMPDetails
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Eid { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string photo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime Dob  { get; set; }
    }


    http://localhost:11113/employeeservice/CreatePerson"
```

How can i pass EMPDetails object to service in android.
I have seen several links. most gives only about a single paramters.

Comment: Please structure better your question, formatting code properly and keep clear you question.

Comment: What data type is the web service expecting?

Comment: It is expecting a type of EMPDetails which is defined as above